# Arcpy - handling intermediate raster files

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

I have 8,760 (24*365) GRID rasters in a directory. I'd like to use use [FocalStatistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000qs000000.htm) analysis to reassign cells to the maximum of a 5x5 window/kernel and extract the resultant values at points specified in a points feature class.

```
from arcpy import CheckOutExtension
    from arcpy.sa import FocalStatistics, NbrRectangle

    if CheckOutExtension("spatial") != 'CheckedOut':
        raise Exception('Failed to check out spatial analyst extension.)

    # Testing subset of raster data. For simplicity.
    HRRR_rasters = [r'E:\HRRR_Data\2014\GRID\1 - JAN_2014\g01010000',
                    r'E:\HRRR_Data\2014\GRID\1 - JAN_2014\g01010100',
                    r'E:\HRRR_Data\2014\GRID\1 - JAN_2014\g01010200',
                    r'E:\HRRR_Data\2014\GRID\1 - JAN_2014\g01010300',
                    r'E:\HRRR_Data\2014\GRID\1 - JAN_2014\g01010400']

    neighborhood = NbrRectangle(width=5, height=5, units="CELL")
    extract_points = r'C:\Users\jking\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\sample_points'


    for raster in HRRR_rasters:
        raster_obj = FocalStatistics(raster, neighborhood, 'MAXIMUM', "DATA")

        # ------------------------Psudocode ------------------------------------
        # ExtractValuesToPoints(in_point_features, in_raster, out_point_features) 

        # arcpy.da.InsertCursor to append to master table.
        # Allow raster object to be garbage collected or deleted.
```

The main problem that I'm having is that [ExtractValuesToPoints](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000002t000000.htm) takes a raster_layer as input rather than a raster object. I have looked into saving the raster to the 'in_memory' workspace without any luck. I've also looked into the properties of the [raster object](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v000000wt000000) finding that raster_obj.catalogPath & raster_obj.path are None. [MakeRasterLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006t000000) takes the path and name of the raster dataset which also doesn't work. I can, albeit reluctantly, save the raster to disc, use it for processing and delete it manually. I would like to avoid this write heavy approach though.

Comment: Try arcpy.Raster("pathToRasterDataset")

Comment: if you use arcpy.env.overwriteoutput you can overwrite a temporary file and/or arcpy.Delete_management to clean it up when you're finished with it. Another handy approach is to test for existence using if arcpy.Exists(TempRaster): arcpy.Delete_management(TempRaster) on the way in to ensure the raster doesn't exist before creating it. Temp raster objects are GRID data in your %Temp% (or was that %tmp%) directory - they are *file system objects* nothing 'magic' about them, only that arcpy knows how to handle them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually works:

```
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = outFolder

raster_obj=FocalStatistics(raster, neighborhood, 'MAXIMUM', "DATA")
raster_obj.save("outZ")
del raster_obj
ExtractValuesToPoints(in_point_features, outFolder+os.sep+"outZ", out_point_features)
```

Comment: Add arcpy.Delete_management(outFolder+os.sep+"outZ") to clean up and it's a good answer Felix.

Comment: Yes, outside loop at the very end. Overwrite output option handles it Ok otherwise

Comment: There is only one raster but you're right.. if you're doing many then just before exiting is the best place to put that.